# How do I make a python program check for a value every time something happens?

Tags: python, text

I'm making a game in python, and it has a health system. Can I make the program check for changes in the `game_state['health']` I have all the time without using `if game_state['health'] = =< 0`?

Comment: Use a function/method to change the health and add your checks there? That concept is called encapsulation in OOP jargon

Comment: I heard about that, but I don't understand the concept of methods.

Comment: Then you should read a basic Python tutorial first. The question you ask doesn't make a lot of sense. Maybe you should reformulate in the form "What concept should I use to solve the problem XYZ" rather than "How do I do [concept that you think solves XYZ, but really isn't a good idea]"

Comment: Isn't a good idea? I said without using if game_state etc... I didn't come up with a plausible solution, I was asking for a solution to my problem. What I want is for a method to check the health every time health reduces, so that if it hits 0, the end will prompt.

I've tried finding a good tutorial on methods, but none of them explain classes or how they work. I am very new to python.

Comment: You are specifically asking "Can I make the program check for changes in XYZ", which is not what you want. There are tons of good tutorials on Python, and all of them explain the concept of classes, for example [the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: @ErikRasmussen The answer to your question is yes (without adding an extra method), but if you don't understand how objects, methods and classes work in Python, you will have a really hard time understanding the code that does what you ask for.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sounded angry, I'm just frustrated with this. If I put in a Class H for an example, and a method that states if health = 0, deathscreen() appears, in the top of the document, would it run the method every line of code or something?

Comment: @Erik: No. If you use OOP here, you'd probably have a class `GameState` that manages the health and other variables of your game. In your game's main loop, you'd have an instance of this class. You'd have a `change_health` method in it, which would ensure that if the resulting health is below zero, an exception is thrown. Then, in your main loop, you'd catch that exception and show  "game over" or something.

Comment: @NiklasB. Why do you think Key-Value-Observer is a bad idea? It's a very useful design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely read up on some educational materials, tutorials, etc.

A basic approach might be something like the following:

```
class MyCharacter(object):
    """Simple Character Class"""

    def __init__(self, health):
        self._health = health

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self._health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, new_value):
        self._health = new_value
        if new_value <= 0:
            print "What's that strange white light...?"
            raise EndGameEvent("Character is dead... :(")

    def takes_damage(self, damage):
        print "Ouch... that really hurt!"
        self.health = self.health - damage
```

Your main game thread would receive the EndGameEvent and act on it appropriately.  I guess this is still using your check, but you don't have to explicitly write a line of code every time you want to check the health status.

Comment: Mind changing your code to use `__init__` instead of a class attribute? I know it works perfectly in this case, but I think it will only confuse the OP.